# Showing a map is not bijective

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

I'm trying to show that the middle third Cantor set expressed in base 3 mapped to the set of real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ expressed in base 2 according to the rule:

$0.a_1a_2a_3...\rightarrow 0.b_1b_2b_3...$

where $b_i=\frac{a_i}{2}$ is not a bijection.

I know that the map is surjective and not injective because some binary decimal has 2 expansions. However, I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: "each binary decimal has 2 expansions" - that's not true. *Some* binary decimals have two representations. Specifically, the ones that terminate have an alternative representation ending in an endless sequence of 1's. All others have only one representation. This gives you a clue how to prove that the map is not injective. Consider $0.2$ and $0.022222...$

Comment: An instance of the comment above from Bungo: $f(1/3)=$ $f((0.0\overline 2)_3)=$ $(0.0\overline 1)_2=$ $1/2=(0.1\overline 0)_2=$ $=f(0. 2\overline 0)_3)=$ $f(2/3).$... BTW, a member ofthe Cantor set has exactly $1$ representation in base-$3$ that does not use the digit $1$. The rule in your Q assumes that every $a_n\in \{0,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each $x \in C$ has a unique representation $x = 0.a_1a_2a_3...$ with $a_i \in \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace$ wheras some $y \in I$ have two distinct representations $y = 0.b_1b_2b_3...$ with $b_i \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ (see Bungo's comment). In other words you have a bijection $\varphi : \Pi_{i=1}^\infty \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace \to C$ and a surjection $\psi : \Pi_{i=1}^\infty \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace \to I$ which is not injective. Your map is the composition $\psi \circ b \circ \varphi^{-1}$, where $b :\Pi_{i=1}^\infty \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace \to \Pi_{i=1}^\infty \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ is the bijection given by $b((a_i)) = (a_i/2)$.

Comment: And if you endow the infinite products with the product topology, then $\varphi$, $b$ are homeomorphisms and $\psi$ is a continuous surjection.